# creating a dictionary from a subset dicts of a nested dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

have to frame a new dict from a subset dicts of a dictionary with some dynamic control.
input data:

```
default_data = {
   'Common':{'name': "Trey", 'website': "http://treyhunner.com"},
   'api1_data':{
       'v1':{'name': "Anonymous User_v1", 'page_name': "Profile Page"},
       'v2': {'name': "Anonymous User_v2", 'page_name': "Profile Page"}},

   'api1_op': [],

   'api2_data':{
       'v1':{'name': "Anonymous User_v1", 'page_name': "Profile Page"},
       'v2': {'name': "Anonymous User_v2", 'page_name': "Profile Page"}},

   'api2_op': [],

   'api3_data':{'name1': "dmm", 'website1': "http://"}
}
```

User controls: 
versions of each api: based on the api version(v1/v2) it should form a dictionary with key as a parent key.

Expected output:

```
op= {'Common':{'name': "Trey", 'website': "http://treyhunner.com"},
     'api1_data': {'name': "Anonymous User_v1", 'page_name': "Profile Page"},
     'api1_op': [],
     'api2_data': {'name': "Anonymous User_v2", 'page_name': "Profile Page"},
     'api2_op': [],
     'api3_data':{'name1': "dmm", 'website1': "http://"}
}
```

Comment: Does the *api**X**_data* need to be selected from the *default_data* according to the selected api version (v1 or v2)?
If true, the *api2_data['name']* should contain "Anonymous User_v1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will take the user selected version and create a **new** dictionary according to his selection.

*Please note, if the user entered not allowed version (not 'v1' or 'v2') it will **raise RuntimeError**.*

```
api_allowed_version = {'v1', 'v2'}
default_data = {
   'Common':{'name': "Trey", 'website': "http://treyhunner.com"},
   'api1_data':{
       'v1':{'name': "Anonymous User_v1", 'page_name': "Profile Page"},
       'v2': {'name': "Anonymous User_v2", 'page_name': "Profile Page"}},

   'api1_op': [],

   'api2_data':{
       'v1':{'name': "Anonymous User_v1", 'page_name': "Profile Page"},
       'v2': {'name': "Anonymous User_v2", 'page_name': "Profile Page"}},

   'api2_op': [],

   'api3_data':{'name1': "dmm", 'website1': "http://"}
}

user_api_version = input('Please choose version (v1/v2): ')
if user_api_version not in api_allowed_version:
    raise RuntimeError('Not allowed api version ({0})'.format(user_api_version))

op = dict(default_data)
for key in op.keys():
   if key.endswith('_data') and user_api_version in default_data[key].keys():
        op[key] = default_data[key][user_api_version]
```

This will result with:

```
{'Common': {'name': 'Trey', 'website': 'http://treyhunner.com'}, 
'api1_data': {'name': 'Anonymous User_v1', 'page_name': 'Profile Page'}, 
'api1_op': [], 
'api2_data': {'name': 'Anonymous User_v1', 'page_name': 'Profile Page'}, 
'api2_op': [], 
'api3_data': {'name1': 'dmm', 'website1': 'http://'}}
```

Due to the fact that this is python there is a need to create a deepcopy of the original dictionary (in this case the *default_data*).
This can be done as in my example (*op = dict(default_data)*) or by

```
import copy
op = copy.deepcopy(default_data)
```